# Using output from BeautifulSoup as input in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm learning python to scrape data from this specific game website. With the help of this community, I got solutions for most of my questions. 
I am trying to scrape data from an airline management game website which shows distance, runway length, passenger demand, etc... between airports. Here is my code

```css
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {'lEmail': '<myEmailid>',
        'lPass': '<Password>',
        'fbSig': 'web'}

login_url = 'https://www.airline4.net/weblogin/login.php'
url = 'https://www.airline4.net/research_main.php?mode=search&rwy=1000&dist=19210&depId=600&arr=0&arrId=0&fbSig=false'

with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(login_url, data=data).text

    # now you are logged in, just print some information:
    distance = 19210
    departure_id = 600
    while distance != 'stop':
        url = 'https://www.airline4.net/research_main.php?mode=search&rwy=1000&dist=' + str(distance) + '&depId=' + str(departure_id) + '&arr=0&arrId=0&fbSig=false'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
  
        distance = input()
```

Here, I am manually entering variable `distance` and using it in my url. 
The output I get is:

```html
C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Project1/Airline3.py
Distance
Y class
J class
F class
Rwy
EHBK
-
NZCI
Netherlands, Maastricht
-
New Zealand, Waitangi
19,208 km
4,462ft rwy
Market:
71%
Y class
211
J class
94
F class
76
EHBK
-
NZDN
Netherlands, Maastricht
-
New Zealand, Dunedin
18,743 km
6,234ft rwy
Market:
38%
Y class
180
J class
122
F class
74
EHBK
-
NZOU
Netherlands, Maastricht
-
New Zealand, Oamaru
18,740 km
4,210ft rwy
Market:
39%
Y class
103
J class
137
F class
44
EHBK
-
NZCH
Netherlands, Maastricht
-
New Zealand, Christchurch
18,722 km
10,787ft rwy
Market:
81%
Y class
253
J class
62
F class
81
EHBK
-
NZTU
Netherlands, Maastricht
-
New Zealand, Timaru
18,704 km
4,200ft rwy
Market:
35%
Y class
289
J class
92
F class
29
```

In this result, Is there any way to use that `18,704 km` as input(should be selected automatically, without my intervention) for my loop?

Comment: We cannot look to the return soup as we need credentials. Could you share the output of `print(soup)` so we can help you ?

Comment: Hi Sir, I couldn't get that `print(soup)` pasted here due to character limit(maybe there's some other way, but i'm newbie here). So I created a dummy account with a temporary mail. So here's username: `ufgqz44810@dfb55.com`  and password: `Airline4`

Comment: I copied result of `print(soup)` to google drive [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vk1hrKsdq1ZcFCXRhOLAtiI9sqJ-ZQWJ/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `findAll` function to get a list of all the balise `div` with the appropriate attribute (see code below). This way, you can loop through each airport.

This way, you can then look for the precise elements you are searching for, and then compute an exit of your choice.

The code needs to be customized, but it is a good starting point.

```py
distance = 19210
departure_id = 600
table = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'row border opa sorter'})
for apt in table:
    apt_detail = apt.findAll('div')
    for elem in apt_detail:
        print(elem.text.split('\n'))
```

output:

```
['', '', '', '     EHBK', '    ', '    -', '    ', '     NZCI', '    ', '', '', '    Netherlands, Maastricht', '   ', '   -', '   ', '    New Zealand, Waitangi', '   ', '', '']
['', '', '     EHBK', '    ', '    -', '    ', '     NZCI', '    ', '']
['', '', '', '     19,208 km', '    ', '', '    4,462ft rwy', '   ', '   Market:', '   ', '    71%', '   ', '']
['', '', '     19,208 km', '    ', '', '    4,462ft rwy', '   ']
...
```